# SSIS Lookup component advanced tab

Tags: sql-server, ssis

In my look up component in the connection tab i wrote a query

```
select * from tableA
```

Again in the **advance tab** of the same look up component I wrote another query with parameters and mapped them correctly to filter the data in `tableA`.
I executed my package and the result is as i expected it to be.

But as this look up needs to be performed on large number of rows i want to know, while my package executes whether it considers the query in connection tab or it considers the parameterized query.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If the advanced tab is editable (i.e. you are using Partial or No Cache Mode) then the parameterized query will be used.

Using partial or no cache will allow you to parameterize query, Note that Partial and No cache mode will be slower. It needs to run the parameterized query every time if in no cache mode, or every time no row in the lookup is found if in partial cache mode.

This link may be helpful: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2008/10/18/lookup-cache-modes.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `No Cache Mode` or `Partial Mode`, think of:
- create a parametrised variable 
- set in source expressions to `SELECT` using created variable

It's much faster, and parametrisation is not much more complicated in most cases.